# Switching boolean data attribute only works once Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attr

I'm creating a todo list, with each todo's HTML div containing a `data-completed="true"` attribute.

I am trying to toggle the completed attribute back and forth when the todo is clicked using Jquery

It switches to false, but when I click again it doesn't switch back. The flipCompleted variable seems to get stuck on false despite the fact the click event is passing in the new value.

```
$("body").on("click", ".todo", function() {
    let id = $(this).data("id")
    let completed = $(this).attr("data-completed")
    // dbMethods.updateTodo(id, completed)
    domMethods.updateTodo.call(this, completed)
    event.stopPropagation()
})
```

```
updateTodo: function(completed) {
        let flipCompleted = !completed
        $(this).children('.todo-title').toggleClass("completed");
        $(this).data("completed", flipCompleted);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="todo" data-id="5de7d31d753b914d6f714cab" data-completed="true">
                <div class="todo-title"><h4>Go to shops</h4></div> 
                <button class="delete"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </div>
```

I've tried changing it with `.attr()` and `.data()` both of which only work once.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just so you know, you can access the 'data-completed' attribute the same way in both scenarios, both setting and getting: `let completed = $(this).data("completed")` instead of `let completed = $(this).attr("data-completed")`

Comment: @TKoL that's in fact the problem here, since using `.data()` to **set** values won't affect the attribute.

Comment: Can you man an example in a codesandbox? That would be helpful for people who want to help you fix this problem

Comment: @Pointy oh! Of course! That makes a lot of sense actually

Comment: created a working jsfiddle with minor adjustments: https://jsfiddle.net/q86dar2w/

Answer (score 2):

The issue might be solvable by fixing an inconsistency in your code. You have this:

```
$("body").on("click", ".todo", function() {
    ...
    // this bit of code right here:
    let completed = $(this).attr("data-completed")
    ...
})
updateTodo: function(completed) {
        ...
        $(this).data("completed", flipCompleted);
    }
```

But you want to use the jQuery `.data` function in both cases

```
$("body").on("click", ".todo", function() {
    ...
    // this bit of code right here:
    let completed = $(this).data("completed")
    ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this has worked! It only shows up in Jquery however, the mark up doesn't change, is this correct?

Comment: I think so. In fact I think that's the crux of hte issue: jquery `.data` doesn't always change the markup

Comment: jquery `.data` supports any kind of object or data structure, but the markup only supports strings. That's why they get desynced I suppose